# How do I set XML attributes in SOAPpy with python?

Tags: python, soappy

I am forming a SOAPpy request but I can't figure out how to set the attributes in a tag.  Here is my code:

```
url = wsdlfile = 'https://stats2.overture.com/ExternalSOAP/statsPMCAPI_1_0.wsdl'
n = 'urn:yahoo:overture:stats:3.0'
server = WSDL.Proxy(wsdlfile)
server.soapproxy.config.dumpSOAPOut = 1
server.soapproxy.config.dumpSOAPIn = 1
result = server.getAvailablePmcReports(ReportAuth = {'username': username, 'cookie': YBY}, ReportRequest= '')
print(result)
```

Which outputs this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:getAvailablePmcReports xmlns:ns1="urn:yahoo:overture:stats:3.0" SOAP-ENC:root="1">
<ReportRequest xsi:type="xsd:string"></ReportRequest>
<ReportAuth>
<username xsi:type="xsd:string">myuser</username>
<cookie xsi:type="xsd:string">cookie here...</cookie>
</ReportAuth>
</ns1:getAvailablePmcReports>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But what I want is this:

```
<ReportRequest startRow="0" shownRows="200">
```

How do I add the attributes?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you, please, provide the complete source XML document and the final XML document that you want to form from it? I may be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by passing a typed value for the ReportRequest keyword argument.  For example, if I change the `getAvailablePmcReports` line to this:

```
from SOAPpy import Types
result = server.getAvailablePmcReports(
    ReportAuth = {'username': username, 'cookie': YBY},
    ReportRequest= Types.stringType('', attrs={'startRow': 0, 'shownRows': 200}))
```

The resulting request includes a tag like this:

```
<ReportRequest xsi:type="xsd:string" shownRows="200" startRow="0"></ReportRequest>
```